# How to return the content of a WordPress Plugin PHP function when the functions is in an included file?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Yes the questions sounds stupid, I am new to Plugins. I viewed into other plugins to solve it, but they are too complicated, when you are new.

All I want is to call a function on a WordPress page /example using a shortcode. The called function should use sub files where other functions are defined.

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Plugin URI:  https://example.com
 * Description: A brief description of my plugin
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Your Name
 * Author URI:  https://example.com
 * License:     GPL2
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain: my-plugin
 * Domain Path: /languages
 */

function iaAddScripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin-style', plugins_url('css/iaStyle.css', __FILE__));
  wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin-script', plugins_url('js/iaScript.js', __FILE__));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'iaAddScripts');

function my_shortcode_function() {
    require (plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/functions/nameToCall.php');
    //return "<p class='testRed'>Hello world!</p>"; //THIS WORKS AND SHOWS Hello World! ON THE PAGE
}

add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function');
```

Here the content of the nameToCall.php

```
<?php
function myFunc(){
    return "<p class='testRed'>Hello world 2!!</p>";
}
myFunc();
```

I would expect, that the function myFunc returns "Hello world 2!!" on the page /demo. But it does not. The text is only shown, when I return it in the main file. (Here with // disabled)

So for me is totally unclear how I can put functions in sub files and show text from there.

Thank you.
Chris

Comment: The problem is, that a shortcode function is supposed to return the value - but your `my_shortcode_function` isn't currently doing that. You are calling `myFunc()` in your include file, that function does return something - but it doesn't then get "passed along" further up the chain.

Comment: I can use ob_start before call function, more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via:

bar.php

```
<?php
function bar(){
   return 'bar';
}
return bar();
```

```
<?php

function foo () {
    return include 'bar.php';
}

var_export(foo());
```